# Button ontouchstart

Tags: css, button, mobile, safari

I created a mobile website with some buttons. I added a background-gradient via css and an inverted gradient for #button:active. When I open my website on my iPhone and tap the button, the gradient changes but there is also the "Mobile-Safari-native"-effect of blanking/darken the button. Is there a way to disable the second effect?

Comment: Your english is perfectly fine, no reason for that excuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

To the CSS for the buttons.

Comment: `.button {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
  font-size: 45px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: left;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#ddd));
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
}



.button:active{
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ddd), to(#fff));
}`

Comment: Check if its not overruled somewhere, or prevent it by adding '!important', like so: -webkit-appearance: none !important;

Comment: no, doesn't work.. still that grey overlay like for links, buttons etc.

Comment: solved it with "-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);"!
But is there a way to trigger the action only when "ontouchend"? Now, when I tap the button and "slide away", the button never the less triggers the action-> function prevent default used to prevent srolling

Comment: I don't understand, which action is triggered? Can you post some code perhaps?

Comment: I have a function called "diesewoche()" (thisweek in german), which is triggered, when I tap the button via onClick="diesewoche();". OnTouchEnd="diesewoche();" doesn't seem to work, does it? So that "diesewoche()" is only triggered, when you tap and release the button and not when you tap and slide away... just in case you "unwittingly" tapped the button

Comment: Ok I think I understand. So you have a button, which you only want to activate when it is pressed and released, and to prevent an accidental slide (starting on that button) triggering diesewoche(); right?

I would say, indeed binding to touchend would fix that:
    $('#button').bind('click touchend',function(e) {  
        // do stuff
    }

If that doesn't work, I'd like to see your code, perhaps in a fiddle. Maybe this plugin will help you out: http://wipetouch.codeplex.com/

Comment: So I haven't use jquere or something else like that yet, just native HTML and JavaScript... I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: I think the problem is, that when I move my finger, the preventDefault function prevents the detection, so the website doesn't even recognize when I slide away.

Comment: preventDefault stops everything from that point, so it's a good chance that it is your problem. Anyway, it is almost impossible to help you without showing any code I'm affraid..

Comment: I just tried it @ iphone, and it works like it should. Every app shows a 'button press' when you accidently start a swipe on it, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

add `border:0;` property in your `.button` class